# Oracle XE 11.2 Export / Import Charset

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I created a database in oracle XE 11.2 that uses charset AL32UTF8 that I now want to export.

When I perform the export, the resulting data appears in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set.

The server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion).

Why is the export from the database in a different charset than the database itself is using?

Answer (score 2):

The export utility will use the `NLS_LANG` environment variable specified for the client session.  If all your data can be represented in the Windows-1252 character set, that shouldn't be an issue.  If you want to do the export using the AL32UTF8 character set, you'd need to set the `NLS_LANG`.  In Windows, that would be something like

```
c:\> set nls_lang = american_america.al32utf8
```

Answer (score -1):

**Steps to migrate the characterset of database**

> Changing character to WE8MSWIN1252:
>
> Take Full export of database before starting this activity...

```
#sqlplus system/admin as sysdba
```

```
SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET' ;

select * from nls_database_parameters ;

set linesize 2000
```

```
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE 
STARTUP MOUNT;
ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
ALTER SYSTEM SET JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES=0;
ALTER SYSTEM SET AQ_TM_PROCESSES=0;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
```

```
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET WE8MSWIN1252;

-- if the above fails:
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE WE8MSWIN1252;
```

```
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE; — or SHUTDOWN NORMAL;
STARTUP;
```

Comment: Explain how changing the character set of database would help to resolve the issue that the OP is concerned.

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET ...` is desupported since Oracle 10R1. You may destroy your database.